# Azure Service Fabric backups (non-persistent data)

Tags: azure, resources, service-fabric-stateless, backups

I have 3 applications deployed to Azure Service Fabric via ARM template. The only items that have been identified as needing to be backed up are some resources. They include a central blob storage, about 5 SQL databases, and the key vault. The cluster and apps can be redeployed right away via the template.

Searching for backup solutions, I'm seeing a lot of info on backups for services, but not for specific resources like I have here. Can anyone point me to the right direction/sample code on how to do this or is it even an option?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so, storage cannot be backed up using Azure services. You have to créate a program\script that will do that for you.

For the keyvault you can use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.keyvault/backup-azurekeyvaultkey?view=azurermps-5.1.1) powershell cmdlet.

For the SQL there are a bunch of ways to do that, but perhaps you can settle with the built-in backup, which happens automatically and goes 7-35 days back (depending on your tier)

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm fairly new to this, so could you elaborate a bit on ways to backup the SQL DBs? I have the databases under one of the resource groups in Azure, but don't see where I can view the backup settings or restore if needed.

Comment: there are no settings, its built-in, like i said. you can click on the restore button at the sql blade to select one of the backups to restore. you could also configure long term retention for sql db, but you would need Azure backup for that

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-recovery-using-backups